# What design patterns are appropriate for data structure modification within Ethereum smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, design-patterns

I am looking to hear about design patterns that people have implemented within Ethereum smart contracts to allow for post deploy modification of data structures.

For example, say I have a contract which contains a struct defining an Address. Should I down the line realise that I want to add an email address property to the Address.. Is there any pre-deployment design pattern consideration that would allow for me to do this.

A little more complex of an example.. If I had two properties of a contract named 'question' and 'answer', and all of a sudden I want to have multiple possible answers.. how would one go about making such a change?

My issue/concern is that if you interface with said contract through a browser for example, you could simply update the contract that the front end points to (post update).. BUT how do you resolve the problem of maintaining any contract data across update deployments..?

Thanks
T

Comment: Some of the answers in this post might help you: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/guidelines-for-designing-contracts-to-handle-bugfixes/2162#2162

Answer (score 4):

### **You need to put in consideration the following:**

*This has to be planed from the start.* You will need to design your smart contract taking in consideration the following 5 points:

1. You have to have a **good testing strategies and tactics**. Because the
   cost of updating the your smart contract can really ruin your life.
2. Keep your smart contracts **modular and fairly separate rules and logic from data structure.** So if you will need to change something, you will change just the related contract and you will not need to change many or all contracts.
3. You should **be prepared by having an [emergency stop or circuit-breaker](https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices/#circuit-breakers-pause-contract-functionality)** to be able to stop all operations during any migration. Because you do not want to be in a situation where people can still update/insert data to the old version of the smart contract while you are migrating and thereafter.
4. You should **previously provided the ability to read all the data from your smart contract**. Of course you can do a permissioned read by restricting reading all data to the owner or any other trusted user or even another smart contract. You will need to read from the old version of your smart contract and insert in the new version.
5. You will use of of the following strategies to communicate with your smart contract. I copied them from [Smart Contact Best Practices](https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices/blob/master/docs/software_engineering.md#upgrading-broken-contracts):

**Upgrading Broken Contracts**

> Code will need to be changed if errors are discovered or if
>   improvements need to be made. It is no good to discover a bug, but
>   have no way to deal with it
>
> ...
>
> However, there are two basic approaches that are most commonly used.
>   The simpler of the two is to have a registry contract that holds the
>   address of the latest version of the contract. A more seamless
>   approach for contract users is to have a contract that forwards calls
>   and data onto the latest version of the contract.

**Example 1: Use a registry contract to store latest version of a contract**

> In this example, the calls aren't forwarded, so users should fetch the
>   current address each time before interacting with it.

```
contract SomeRegister {
    address backendContract;
    address[] previousBackends;
    address owner;

    function SomeRegister() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner)
        _;
    }

    function changeBackend(address newBackend) public
    onlyOwner()
    returns (bool)
    {
        if(newBackend != backendContract) {
            previousBackends.push(backendContract);
            backendContract = newBackend;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

> There are two main disadvantages to this approach:
>
> 1. Users must always look up the current address, and anyone who fails
>      to do so risks using an old version of the contract
> 2. You will need to think carefully about how to deal with the contract
>      data when you replace the contract
>
> The alternate approach is to have a contract forward calls and data to
>   the latest version of the contract:

**Example 2: Use a DELEGATECALL to forward data and calls**

```
contract Relay {
    address public currentVersion;
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function Relay(address initAddr) {
        currentVersion = initAddr;
        owner = msg.sender; // this owner may be another contract with multisig, not a single contract owner
    }

    function changeContract(address newVersion) public
    onlyOwner()
    {
        currentVersion = newVersion;
    }

    function() {
        require(currentVersion.delegatecall(msg.data));
    }
}
```

> This approach avoids the previous problems but has problems of its
>   own. You must be extremely careful with how you store data in this
>   contract. If your new contract has a different storage layout than the
>   first, your data may end up corrupted. Additionally, this simple
>   version of the pattern cannot return values from functions, only
>   forward them, which limits its applicability. ([More complex
>   implementations](https://github.com/ownage-ltd/ether-router) attempt to solve this with in-line assembly code
>   and a registry of return sizes.)
>
> Regardless of your approach, it is important to have some way to
>   upgrade your contracts, or they will become unusable when the
>   inevitable bugs are discovered in them.

I created a story on Medium for this with title: [Essential Design Consideration for Ethereum dApps (1): Upgradeable Smart Contracts](https://medium.com/@maltabba/essential-design-consideration-for-ethereum-dapps-1-upgradeable-smart-contracts-b4fb21e1fd89)

Answer (score 2):

We could also fall back on a VARIANT type solution (yes, I don't like it either).
Have a mapping (uint => StorageItem).

- The uint is a field ID.
- The StorageItem contract would have a string value and an integer type.  The type would allow you convert from the string to the needed end type.

One weakness here is that at some point, solidity will support new types that we'll want to take advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could keep the storage in a separate contract as suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/guidelines-for-designing-contracts-to-handle-bugfixes/2162#2162) but the struct would keep the data in a JSON (string) object. Then you can make any modifications you need (extend or change the model).

for example:

```
{"address": "Some Street","phone": 123456}
```

would become

```
{"address": "Some Street","phone": 123456, "email":"someone@email.com"}
```

You can handle missing values on the client side or in the calling contract.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches using which **you can upgrade a `Contract1` to `Contract2`, keeping its state(data & balance) with the same address as before.**

**How does this work?**
A way is to use a proxy contract with a `fallback` function where each method call/trx is delegated to the implementation contract (which contains all the logic).
[image]

A delegate call is similar to a regular call, except that all code is executed in the context of the caller (proxy), not of the callee (implementation). Because of this, a transfer in the implementation contract’s code will transfer the proxy’s balance, and any reads or writes to the contract storage will read or write from the proxy’s storage.

In this approach, users only interact with the proxy contract and we can change the implementation contract while keeping the same proxy contract.

[image]

The `fallback` function will execute on any request, redirecting the request to the implementation and returning the resulting value (using opcodes).

This was a basic explanation which is enough for us to work with upgradeable contracts. In case, you want to dig deep into proxy contract code and different proxy patterns, then check out these posts.

- [How to Write Upgradable Smart Contracts (Smart Contract Versioning)](https://simpleaswater.com/upgradable-smart-contracts/?ref=eth_stackexchange)
- [How Upgradable Smart Contracts work Under the Hood](https://simpleaswater.com/how-upgradable-smart-contracts-work-under-the-hood/?ref=eth_stackexchange)

**How can I write upgradable smart contracts?**

[OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades/2.7/) provides awesome [CLI tools](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts#upgrading-a-contract-via-cli) & [JS Libraries](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts#upgrading-contracts-in-js) that take care of all the above complex `proxy` contracts, linking it to implementation (logic) contract & managing all the contracts you deploy using the CLI for upgradability, out-of-the-box.

The only thing you need to do is to write your contracts, and use OpenZeppelin CLI or Libraries to deploy the contracts.

> NOTE: There are a [few
>   Limitations](https://simpleaswater.com/upgradable-smart-contracts/#a-few-things-to-keep-in-mind-limitations-workarounds)
>   that you should be aware of, in terms of how you need to write your
>   contracts and how you should upgrade them. There are also a number of
>   workarounds these limitations in [this
>   post](https://simpleaswater.com/upgradable-smart-contracts/#a-few-things-to-keep-in-mind-limitations-workarounds).