# Deploy contract without losing database

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

I have implemented improved token at: https://ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code

I use truffle to test and use migrations to deploy contract.

When I want to deploy a new version of `MyAdvancedToken`, I don't want to lose the values of 'balanceOf' in the `token` contract.

But when i create a new contract like `MyAdvancesToken1` it compiles `token` and deploy to new address. Is there anyway to deploy a new contract without losing balance database?

Comment: There's no trivial way to do this, and it may not be desirable in the case of a token. Have a look here for some indications of the big topics: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/should-governance-and-token-smart-contracts-be-unstoppable-or-upgradeable Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, you will need some contract logic handling that

[This article](https://blog.colony.io/writing-upgradeable-contracts-in-solidity-6743f0eecc88) describes one approach.

Comment: welcome to the community :) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) for more guide on formatting