# How to delete or bug fix smart contracts

Tags: contract-development

If I plan to have a develop on DApp, how can I retain control over it. Either for doing further enhancements or bug fixes. Can I able to delete any abandoned contracts?

Comment: Please see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-contracts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete abandoned contracts. Have a look at the [greeter](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) contract.

```
/* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); }
```

Contracts have a **selfdestruct()** method that allows an account to retrieve its funds.