# Simpler examples of contract versioning

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, upgrading, delegatecall

I want to have an `upgradable contract` so that I can have additional functionalities in upgraded contract. I know there are numerous of questions around it, most of them pointing towards [Upgradable Contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-contracts). I tried to understand the codes from [here](https://gist.github.com/tjade273/69e3cb5dce1789738830) and [writing upgradable contracts in solidity](https://blog.colony.io/writing-upgradeable-contracts-in-solidity-6743f0eecc88#.bvv75lozz), but failed. Are there any simpler examples illustrating the `versioning system`. Any sample codes that illustrate how to have upgradable contract in simpler way.

Comment: One link - https://blog.colony.io/writing-upgradeable-contracts-in-solidity-6743f0eecc88#.vt8kwselt