# eval type functionality

Tags: solidity

Languages such as javascript and Perl have eval statement. Is it possible to have 
some functionalty similar to eval in Solidity ?

In particular, this is what I want to do:
Suppose I deploy a contract A.  A should have a function that takes 
address, function name and parameters of a contract that it can call.
When I deploy a different contract B sometime later, I want to be able 
to call A's function and pass B's address, function name and parameters and 
have A call it.

Please note that at the time of deployment of A, I do not know the name of 
B's function and its signature. J

Comment: eval is an insecure function so why to implement it in a limited language like solidity

Comment: Suppose some "thing" is represented by a contract (A) which has been deployed.   Then what this contract can do is fixed. If I want it to call the function of another contract (e.g. B) which is deployed later and whose signature (prototype)  i do not know in advance, I cannot .

Comment: so look at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts