# Can data in an old contract still be accessed?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, upgrading

What happens if data is created via a contract address and then a new contract is used? Can all the old data be accessed still?

I saw this - [Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts) - which outlines ideas from 2016, is that still the best advice for contract management?

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Yes [Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts) is where these answers are, and anyone can add new answers to it. Any old answers can be downvoted. Will edit the title of this question to be more accurate and mark this as duplicate so that answers can be added to one spot and anyone looking for upgrading contracts doesn't have to search in many places.  (I've still upvoted this question for effort.)

Comment: If the relevance of this question was can data in a self-destructed contract still be accessed, please ask it in a new post (if it hasn't been answered on this site already) :)