# Can smart contracts become incompatible with new versions of the EVM?

Tags: contract-design, evm, upgrading

Can the EVM update deprecate operations of older smart contracts, making these contracts non-operative? If so, what are the solutions to upgrade these smart contracts to the new version of the EVM if they cannot be modified directly (due to immutability)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts)

Comment: This is a corollary of the question you flagged as duplicate. This one relates to the situation where the contract owner does not wish to upgrade the contract. This question is: will an upgrade to the platform force the owner to upgrade (or deprecate, or delete) the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and in fact some [already have](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/57ork1/ive_made_a_list_of_contracts_which_will_be_100/) in the past due to changes to the gas schedule.

Designing a contract to be upgradeable like xgabrielx said is a good practice due to unforeseen changes and problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, over time some functions might be depricated (as is standard procedure, not limited to EVM).

(1) You deploy a new contract, telling users to start using that instead.

(2) You have a fronting contract which points to the "latest" version of you main contract.

(3) Use ENS to mycontract.eth and point it to the latest version of your contract.