# How to make function call through relay / entry level contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, fallback-function, delegatecall

I am trying to create an entry level contract (one that is the entry point):

> Relay.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
contract Relay {
    address public currentVersion;
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            throw;
        }
        _;
    }

    function Relay(address initAddr) {
        currentVersion = initAddr;
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    function changeContract(address newVersion) public
    onlyOwner()
    {
        currentVersion = newVersion;
    }

    function() {
        if(!currentVersion.delegatecall(msg.data)) throw;
    }
}
```

And my contract

> Access2.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
import './Storage.sol';
import './Relay.sol';

contract Access2{
Storage s;
address Storageaddress=0xcd53170a761f024a0441eb15e2f995ae94634c06;

function Access2(){
Relay r=new Relay(this);
}

 function createEntity(string entityAddress,uint entityData)public returns(uint rowNumber){
        s = Storage(Storageaddress);
        uint row=s.newEntity(entityAddress,entityData);
        return row;
    }

    function getEntityCount()public constant returns(uint entityCount){
        s = Storage(Storageaddress);
        uint count=s.getEntityCount();
        return count;
    }   
}
```

Both the contracts are deployed.

If I access the method of Access2 via web3 using the object of Access2 it works fine, but now the problem is how can I access the the method of Access2 via Relay.

Can I use the Object of `Relay`?

This will look like duplicate of up-gradable contract [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts) 
but my question is not about writing upgradable contract but calling the functions of our contract from the entry level contract:
i.e. how does the concept of entry level contract work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts)

Comment: @niksmac, Not actually a duplicate, But next step or further explanation of answer to  Upgradeable smart contracts

Comment: I think that the desired functionality of this question is similar to the one used for the Multisig Exploit; call a function of Access2 contract using the fallout function of Relay contract. More details in   http://hackingdistributed.com/2017/07/22/deep-dive-parity-bug/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from `Relay` you can call `Access2` functions, like `createEntity`.

The important code in `Relay` that makes it happen is its [fallback-function](/questions/tagged/fallback-function):

```
function() {
    if(!currentVersion.delegatecall(msg.data)) throw;
}
```

It is helpful to read the questions and answers on [fallback-function](/questions/tagged/fallback-function) to learn more about them.

Basically, when you invoke (call) `createEntity` in `Relay`, because `Relay` doesn't have a `createEntity` function, the fallback function of `Relay` will be called.  The value of `currentVersion` is your instance of `Access2`, so it will do `delegatecall(msg.data)` on that `Access2` instance.  `msg.data` contains the information which will then invoke the `createEntity` function on that `Access2` instance.

Another way of putting it: you ask `Relay` to run some data (call function `createEntity` with certain data and arguments), but since `Relay` doesn't know how to handle that data, it will pass the data along to `Access2`.

Comment: `Basically, when you invoke (call) createEntity in Relay, because Relay doesn't have a createEntity function, the fallback function of Relay will be called.`  what will be the web3 command to for invoking createEntity in relay ?

Comment: @A.K. That's a good question and asked in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23369/fallback-function-in-web3

Comment: that question is also not answered

Comment: @A.K. It has an answer now and it's to use `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.  The `data` corresponding to calling `createEntity` will need to be specified according to the [tag:abi].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an instance of your `Relay` contract to call functions of the linked instance of the `Access2` contract.

I created the following minimal example that you could test in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/):

```
contract target {
    event something();
    function doSomething() {
        something();
    }
}

contract relay {
    target myTarget;

    function relay() {
        // this will deploy a new target contract, you could also just set its address
        myTarget = new target();
    }

    function relayCall() {
        myTarget.doSomething();
    }
}
```

To test this, you can create an instance of `relay` (which creates an instance of `target` in its constructor). When you then call `relayCall` it will call the `doSomething` function of that `target` instance. You will correspondingly see the event `something` being called.

Not that it matters but for completeness: there is a small issue in your `Access2` contract:

```
function Access2(){
Relay r=new Relay(this);
}
```

Here `this` is the address of the current instance of `Access2` (which is not of type `Relay`). Since you dont call anything on that `r` object all is fine. But you would most likely into runtime errors when trying to access functions that do not exist (since you assign an `Access2` instance to an object of type `Relay`).

Comment: I think you got me wrong, Its not about calling functions of other contract,

Comment: But that is what you wrote: "how can I access the the method of Access2 via Relay" - if that is not what you meant please rephrase your question.

Comment: Hi @SwapnilKumbhar Please ask the question that you intended as a new question. This question is still helpful for the community so we can keep this one but make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: @ValidityLabs-Sebastian, Agree!! to avoid this confusion, I posted the code for both the contracts, which are clearly illustrating my question