# Fallback function in web3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, fallback-function

I find answer how to make upgradable contract  [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts)

How to call function from currentVersion with fallback function on web3?

```
    contract Relay {
    address public currentVersion;
    address public owner;

    function Relay(address initAddr){
        currentVersion = initAddr;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function update(address newAddress){
        if(msg.sender != owner) throw;
        currentVersion = newAddress;
    }

    function(){
        if(!currentVersion.delegatecall(msg.data)) throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20972/how-to-make-function-call-through-relay-entry-level-contract

Comment: I am also trying to get the answer of this question.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the [sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) function, like so:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: sendingAccount,
  to: contract.address,
  data: yourData, // optional, if you want to pass data or specify another function to be called by delegateCall you do that here
  gas: requiredGas, // technically optional, but you almost certainly need more than the default 21k gas
  value: value //optional, if you want to pay the contract Ether
});
```

Comment: will `contract.address` be the address of Relay or the actual contract?

Comment: And what/how do I write instead of `yourData` (I want to call a method `set()` from a contract `Contract1`. This doesn't seem to work:
```var addDetails = await Contract1.set(1)
 var encodedABI = addDetails.encodeABI(); ```
And instead of  `yourData` I wrote `encodedABI`. Using web3 0.20.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need it anymore, but you can retype the Relay address to instance contract:

```
contract Instance{
   function doSomething(){ ... }
}
```

and then
if Relay.deployed() is at address 0x12345678, do:

```
in = Instance.at('0x12345678')
in.then(function(i){ i.doSomething(); })
```