# Modify string in contract (Error: invalid address)

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I'm trying to write a contract that has a string that can be modified/updated by the owner later on.  I tested it in Remix and it works perfectly. But when I deploy it to my private blockchain, I get errors. Any ideas? Or is there at least a reasonable way to debug the code? These errors seem to be useless!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract c5 {
    uint currentVersion;
    string command;
    address owner;

    //Constructor is automatically executed upon creation:
    function c5(){
            currentVersion = 1;
            command = "test1";
            owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function update(uint input){
            if(msg.sender != owner) return;
            currentVersion = input;
    }

    function query() constant returns (string){
            return command;
    }

    function version() constant returns (uint){
            return currentVersion;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get in the geth console:

```
> c5.query()
"test1"
> c5.version()
1
> c5.update("4")
Error: invalid address
at web3.js:3879:15
at web3.js:3705:20
at web3.js:4948:28
at map (<native code>)
at web3.js:4947:12
at web3.js:4973:18
at web3.js:4998:23
at web3.js:4061:16
at apply (<native code>)
at web3.js:4147:16
```

Are these strings indeed editable? or do I need to submit a new contract with the new string and direct queries to it via an updated address via DELEGATECALL:

[Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts)

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `update` function in your contract is a setter, it would require an account address to execute.

In Remix it automatically sets a default account.

Try to set the default account and then execute:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Hope this helps...!

Comment: Error is mainly due to lack of account address.You need to some how attach an account to your call. Can you give a try with c5.update("4"{from: <your account address>})

Comment: Do you mean like this?
`> c5.update("4"{from:"0x6dd4530a254de371110f88322a67c7d77dc60790"})`
I tried several variants of that with quotes and commas added as well but always got errors like this:
`(anonymous): Line 1:14 Unexpected token { (and 2 more errors)`

Comment: It should be working. You can try compiling code again and then test because there doesn't seems to be anything wrong in the code.

Comment: I think I figured out what you guys were getting at; now the errors are gone and I get a confirmation hexadecimal string of some type, after trying this: `> c5.updateV(44321,{from: eth.accounts[0]}) "0x46e2ad3a25b00aa12624093492c1b84ee28b9f4aee6c632cca363d4d756c72cc"`

Note to future persons, that you won't notice the updated value via the query command until after a block has been mined.
`> miner.start(1)
null
> miner.stop()
true
> c5.query()
44321`

Comment: Good point to note it down.

Comment: both of these solutions work but the running of `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]` by itself first in the console is the cleanest and easiest.

Comment: @Abhishek - where do we run this `web3` command? it has to be part of `.sol` file? Can we do something with `eris-contracts`

Comment: As web3 is a javascript library for interacting with ethereum, you can run the web3 commands on any javascript console or file. I am not sure if it works for eris contracts.