# What should I do if I want to add a new method to the token that has been deployed to ethereum

Tags: solidity, web3js, cpp-ethereum

I have issued a token in the ethereum,but now I need to add a new function to this token,Is there any good case to refer to?

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2404/12555

Comment: Make sure to write your contracts so they are updateable!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you'll have to redeploy.  As carlolm's link shows, you can make ways to actually upgrade your contract in the future.

Here's an article on forking a token which is sort of what you're trying to do:
https://medium.com/@edmundedgar/what-happens-when-you-try-to-fork-an-ethereum-token-863e3defcf7