# ERC20 smart contracts

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I deployed an ERC20 smart contract, but I need to make some changes on it. How do I do that? Heard that it is not possible to do it, once the contract is deployed. An experienced developer must have an alternative available. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is not currently possible to update a deployed smart contract. If you want to build "updatable" smart contracts in the future you could follow the pattern given in this answer [Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts)

Comment: Great Adil, your reply did help.  Thanks ever so much. All the best!