# A bug in my smart contract

Tags: contract-development

What if I find a bug in my published smart contract? What is the best way to resolve it? I guess I can't undo the contract and some folks can still use it?

Comment: You might find this an interesting read: https://medium.com/@tjayrush/smart-contracts-are-immutable-thats-amazing-and-it-sucks-e0fbc7b0ec16

Comment: you have to make it upgradable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An already published contract. Realistically,(you could get a fork that makes the contract invalid similar to the DAO) nothing, but there are [smart contract upgradability patters](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts) that you can develop around to offer some peace of mind and flexibility in fixing bugs of deployed contracts.