# Extend old contract or deploy new after fixing, recommendation?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

Unfortunately, we used different transfer function name in our smart contract which causes issues for us to list it on some exchange, transfer function name should be `transfer` but we used `transferTokens` which is not erc20 now :( 
I want to ask, to use transfer function so should we extend the old contract somehow or should we deploy new contract on ethereum? Which approach is better? If we need to extend then how can we do it and what are the major issues of contract extend?

Thank you.

Comment: If no one has traded on your contract yet (i.e., all balances are 0), then definitely fix and redeploy it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to update the existing smart contract unless you built-in [an upgrade mechanism](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/80206/620). Your best solution is to redeploy the token and start from the scratch.