# How to change SYMBOL of coin?

Tags: remix

**I want to change my token coin symbol name**

I made a coin on the remix but I mistakenly write the Full coin name on the symbol so I want to change my coin symbol

Comment: Once contract is deployed and the symbol variable is hardcoded ( not including logic to update it ) it cannot be changed anymore. If you want achieve that you will have to redeploy your contract, but you will lose any data that your current token holds ( holders, balanced, allowances, etc ).

Comment: A contract state cannot be changed unless the contract has a function to allow changing the state. A more general approach is to use  upgradeable contracts to change the whole bytecode https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts.