# Why do we need to separate storage and logic layers for proxy patterns?

Tags: solidity, contract-upgrading

I'm recently learning proxy patterns (https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/) and understand that although it is not possible to upgrade the code of your already deployed smart contract, it is possible to set-up a proxy contract architecture that will allow you to use new deployed contracts as if your main logic had been upgraded. My question is:

- Why do we need to separate storage and logic layers for proxy patterns?
- What does separating storage and logic layers have relations to contracts being upgradable?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need to separate storage and logic layers for proxy patterns?

[Most proxies today use DELEGATECALL pattern.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts)

- Smart contract loads implementation (code) from one address
- Another smart contract address stores data
- When the smart contract is upgraded, the address where the code is loaded is changed
- The storage address stays the same

Comment: You mentioned "smart contract" several times in your post, which "smart contracts" are you referring to for each bullet point?

Comment: Two smart contracts used in the delegacall proxy pattern.

Comment: I'm asking which is the proxy and which is the logic contract?

Comment: Please see the linked answer for details.